# Adding SIMCOM SIM 900A to Arduino Fire Fighter Robot for sending alert messages

Tags: gsm

I had made Arduino Fire Fighter Robot. I want to add SIMCOM SIM 900A GSM module to Arduino. When flame sensor will detect fire then " Fire!!!" message will be sent to mobile phone and when fire is extinguished then " No fire!!" will be sent to mobile phone. So  how can I add the part of SIMCOM SIM 900A GSM in my project?
Here is the code:

```
 #include <Servo.h>


Servo myservo;

#include <LiquidCrystal.h>  

LiquidCrystal lcd(30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35);   

#define Left_S       9                       // left    sensor
#define Right_S      8                       // right   sensor
#define Forward_S   23                       // forward sensor

#define LM1         52                       // for pump motor     
#define LM2         53                       // for pump motor

#define IN1          5                       // for motor  
#define IN2          4                       // for motor    
#define IN3          3                       // for motor
#define IN4         22                       // for motor


int LEDR     = 36;                           // for danger signal
int LEDB     = 37;                           // for safe signal
int buzz     = 38;                           // for led or buzzer
int pos      =  0;    
int Contrast = 20;                           // for adjusting the brightness of the LCD , 20 is selected for the contrast of LCD

boolean fire = false;

void setup() {

    analogWrite(6, Contrast);

    lcd.begin(16, 2);

    pinMode( Forward_S         , INPUT  );
    pinMode( Left_S            , INPUT  );
    pinMode( Right_S           , INPUT  );
    
    pinMode( LM1               , OUTPUT );
    pinMode( LM2               , OUTPUT );

    pinMode( IN1               , OUTPUT );
    pinMode( IN2               , OUTPUT );
    pinMode( IN3               , OUTPUT );
    pinMode( IN4               , OUTPUT );

    pinMode( buzz              , OUTPUT );

    pinMode( LEDR              , OUTPUT );
    pinMode( LEDB              , OUTPUT );   // xxxxxxxxxxxxx        duplicate
    

    myservo.attach(25);
    myservo.write(90);
}

void put_off_fire() {

    delay (500);

    digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(IN2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(IN3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(IN4, HIGH);

    digitalWrite(LM1, HIGH); 
    digitalWrite(LM2, LOW );
    delay(500);

    for (pos = 50; pos <= 130; pos += 1) { 
        myservo.write(pos); 
        delay(10);  
    }

    for (pos = 130; pos >= 50; pos -= 1) { 
        myservo.write(pos); 
        delay(10);
    }

    digitalWrite(LM1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LM2, LOW);

    myservo.write(90);                       // xxxxxxxxxxxxx        duplicate

   fire = false;                            // xxxxxxxxxxxxx        not needed
}


void loop() {

    myservo.write(90);                       // xxxxxxxxxxxxx        duplicate
//  Sweep_Servo();    

    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);

    fire = true;                             // preset the state (gets cleared when no fire is detected

    if (digitalRead(Left_S) == 0) {          // If Fire is left ahead

        lcd.print("Flame on Left");

        digitalWrite(IN1 , LOW);            // Move the robot left
        digitalWrite(IN2 , HIGH );
        digitalWrite(IN3 , HIGH);
        digitalWrite(IN2 , LOW );
    }

    else if (digitalRead(Forward_S) == 0) {  // If Fire is straight ahead

        lcd.print("Flame on front");
         digitalWrite(IN1 , LOW);            // Move the robot right
        digitalWrite(IN2 , HIGH);
        digitalWrite(IN3 , LOW);
        digitalWrite(IN4 , HIGH);



           }

    else if (digitalRead(Right_S) == 0) {    // If Fire is to the right

        lcd.print("Flame on Right");

        digitalWrite(IN1 , HIGH);            // Move the robot right
        digitalWrite(IN2 , LOW);
        digitalWrite(IN3 , LOW);
        digitalWrite(IN4 , HIGH );
    }

    else {                                   // fire was not detected by any of the sensors

        fire = false;

        lcd.print("No flame");

        digitalWrite(IN1 , HIGH);            // Do not move the robot
        digitalWrite(IN2 , HIGH);
        digitalWrite(IN3 , HIGH);
        digitalWrite(IN4 , HIGH);
    }

    delay(300);                              // Slow down the speed of robot

    if (fire) {
        
        digitalWrite(LEDR, HIGH);            // do fire lights
        digitalWrite(LEDB, LOW);
        digitalWrite(buzz, HIGH);

        put_off_fire();
      //  delay(100);
    }

    else {
        
        digitalWrite(LEDR, LOW );            // do nofire lights
        digitalWrite(LEDB, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(buzz, LOW );

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your actual problem in doing so? Have you googled for tutorials about the SIM900 and have you tried some example codes, to learn how it works? There are tons of information about the SIM900 out there

Comment: I have tried but I couldn't. I bought SIMCOM SIM 900 module which supports 2G SIM but 2G SIM is no longer available in our country. Then I bought SIMCOM SIM900A but I couldn't connect the GSM module with the above code though I saw many examples. And there are various types of circuit of SIMCOM SIM 900A. Which one should I follow? That's why I am facing difficulty in adding the part of sending alert messages with the above code.

Comment: If this is a school project, why not try something where you control all the radio equipment.  Such as LORA?  This may simplify your efforts and code.  If this is a one-off project (you are not sensitive to cost), why not try to use a cell phone as a gate-way to an existing cell phone network.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. As I had already submitted the concept paper of my project, so there is no scope of changing the concept paper and I have to use SIMCOM SIM 900A module.

Comment: As I remember the SIM900A is interfaced via Serial (UART), which means, that no big circuit is involved. Just power supply and RX and TX pins connected. What types of different circuit have you seen? Can you provide links to show, what caused your confusion about the circuit?